# modifying touch events values android

Tags: android, touch

for example I will set ,touch height : -200
so when my finger touches the screen, the touch will happen at a height of -200 from my finger.
(while ignoring the real touch point)

I want the touches to be applied outside of the app.

also Im using root permission in order to use getevent and sendevent.

thanks

Comment: You should mention whether this only applies to your app or outside of it as well.

Comment: edited, (outside of the app)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible with out changing the kernel it self, but may I ask why you need that for? It's a very poor UX experience

Comment: well the idea is to bring ipad gestures to android, by tricking the system .
so when i put 4 finger on the screen the touch events are being pushed down, and because of that im able to pull up the "recent apps" menu (with the android 10 gestures navigation)
, I also thought of when detecting 4 fingers , to bring a transparent window to the front , which will block the touches and the app will interpret those touches accordingly.

Comment: So you mean height +200, not -200. The higher the Y value, the lower the touch on the screen. But I think having a different app appearing on the bottom when you detect 4 fingers would be simpler. Do note that Android changed the behavior of that, you won't be able to appear above system apps and things like that.

Comment: so it wont work when the user is on the settings app for example ,right?
I guess thats good enough, ill try doing it that way than. thank you

Comment: Yes, won't work on settings app, won't appear above status bar but most importantly, may not appear above navigation bar so if user will swipe from bottom up (to show navigation bar) your app will need to manage to handle that as well

Comment: Take a look at similar usecases like recording/faking touch events, you should find relevant stuff there. There are root apps that do that, so it's possible in theory. Removing the original touch event could be harder though

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.